# How to make call with twilio connect using twilio js device client?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to integrate Twilio Connect to allow my web app  users to  make calls through their twilio account so that it charges their account and they can also make international call if their twilio account permits

When user authorizes connect app it seems to return back account sid which i save in database and later i use this account sid when that user makes call. But this doesn't seem to work, i am getting signature mismatch error when making calls using that account sid.

I am using twilio js device client for making browser outbound call.

What  am i missing? Is it possible to make call with twilio connect using twilio js device client?

Comment: At what stage you get the signature mismatch error? And what is the code that is throwing that error?

Comment: @philnash That is the eror twilio browser client throws on browser console when i make outbound call using user's provided account sid. Do  i need to create twiml app on users twilio account through api?

Comment: Right now i am using  auth token of my account, users provided account sid and twiml app sid of my account to generate token which is being used by twilio browser client, it works when i use my own acxount sid

Comment: To be honest, I've not tried this before. I do know that you are performing actions on behalf of a user rather than within your own account, so you need to use the resources of that account, including TwiML Apps and, if relevant to your use case, phone numbers. So, I would definitely set up a TwiML app within their account for this usage.